# Check if valid right angle from sides a,b ,c. BUT you can not use loops, conditionals, arrays or more advanced features

Tags: java

I have integers a, b and c.

Valid right angle means all the sides are positive integers, and they make a valid right angle triangle.

I'll then have to output the result (easy).

Full disclaimer: [This is the course and assignment that I'm trying to finish](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cs-programming-java/programming/n30Yv/hello-world/)

My attempt (Java):

```
// int a, b, c = 3, 4, 5;
// how do I even start checking if I'm not allowed to use "if / else"
// therefore not shown in code

int aSquare = a * a;
int bSquare = b * b;
int cSquare = c * c;
// *Im hoping they dont flag this as a conditional
System.out.println(
        (aSquare == (bSquare + cSquare) || bSquare == (cSquare + aSquare)
                || cSquare == (aSquare + bSquare))
);
```

Comment: Checking the negativity: `boolean minbool = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(a, b, C)) < 0;`

Comment: and then what do I do with the result? I literally can't use an if else block

Comment: use a ternary: `System.out.println(minbool ? "false" : "true");`

Comment: @thibsc `System.out.println(!minbool);` would suffice.

Comment: @hev1, Effectively, not wide awake ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest side is the minimum of `a`, `b`, and `c`; the largest side is the maximum of `a`, `b`, and `c`; and the other side is the sum of `a`, `b`, and `c` subtract the smallest side and the largest side. Then, all we need to do is check if the smallest side is larger than 0 and the square of the smallest side plus the square of the middle side is equal to the square of the largest side.

```
final int smallest = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
final int largest = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
final int middle = a + b + c - smallest - largest;
System.out.println(smallest > 0 && smallest * smallest + middle * middle == largest * largest);
```

Comment: checking smallest > 0 is enough

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? I'll do just that thank you. Will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Based on the nature of the question, it is more meaningful to use `assert` in case if the user inputted a negative number:

```
 assert a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0: "Sides can not be negative";
```

Also, you can use bitwise operators to extract sign of an integer:

```
// sign is 1 if i is zero, 0 if it is negative, 2 if it is positive 
int sign = 1 + (i >> 31) - (-i >> 31);
```